# Android Build Error Using html2pdf plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I had actually posted a question a few days ago regarding the same issue. I had fixed it before, but I just can't remember how I did, though the fix ended up being completely unrelated to the error I was looking at. I'm working on an Android app using Cordova and keep getting errors while building. They all relate to the html2pdf plugin for cordova at https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-html2pdf. The issue is that the plugin requires using iText.jar, which I can't seem to get Cordova to find.

As you can see in the following snippet, when building the app, it sees the required .jar file:

```
-pre-compile:
    [echo] Set jars path to: C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\BatNetting\platforms\
android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar;C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\BatNetting\
platforms\android\libs\iText-4.2.0-com.itextpdf.jar;C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\
BatNetting\platforms\android\libs\jshybugger-library.jar
```

However, once it moves on to the compile stage, it begins to find errors only in the html2pdf plugin:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 35 source files to C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\BatNetting\
platforms\android\ant-build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\thoams\Desktop\batapp\BatNetting\platforms\android\src\at\modalog\
cordova\plugin\html2pdf\Html2pdf.java:14 error: package com.lowagie.text does not exist
    [javac] import com.lowagie.text.Document;
    [javac]                        ^
```

I've tried to look at the other plugins that include .jar files as well and have only found to include `<source-file src="src/android/iText-4.2.0-com.itextpdf.jar" target-dir="libs/"/>` in the plugin.xml file.

The app works fine on iOS and was working a few days ago until this morning. I rebuilt the Android version and began getting errors. Any help at all will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it figured out. Apparently with iText 4.2.0, the namespaces were changed. Because of that, it kept throwing errors when the html2pdf plugin called the namespaces. I guess in iText 5.0, the namespaces were changed from lowagie to iText.